# How to decode base64 to file without knowing the filetype before hand?

Tags: grails

My method is supposed to accept base64 and turn it into a file. In grails, I am aware that there is `Base64.decodeToFile(stringInBase64, fileName)` but, what I'm given is just the base64, and no fileName/extension. Is there a way for me to transform the base64 string into a file without knowing the fileName? Something like, `Base64.decodeToFile(stringInBase64)`? My method should accept, png and ico extensions. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[String.decodeBase64()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#decodeBase64()) will return a `byte[]`. You can [append](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#append(byte[])) it to a `File`.